# Webflux collectMap resulting Mono<Map<String, Mono<String>>>

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm quite new in the reactive world

My code looks like this:

```
    Flux.fromIterable(list)
                    .collectMap(a -> a.getName(),
                            b-> functionReturningMonoOfC(b)
                            .map(C::url)
                    .block();
```

The result is of type `Map<String, Mono<String>>` . I would like it to be of type `Map<String, String>`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use [`flatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) operator before collecting the elements into a `Map`

```
public class ReactorApp {

    record Person(String name){}

    public static Mono<String> functionReturningMono(Person person) {
        return Mono.just("Hello " + person.name());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = List.of(
                new Person("John"),
                new Person("Mike"),
                new Person("Stacey")
        );

        Map<String, String> result = Flux.fromIterable(persons)
                .flatMap(person -> functionReturningMono(person)
                        .map(String::toUpperCase)
                        .map(message -> Map.entry(person.name(), message)))
                .collectMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)
                .block();

        System.out.println("Result : " + result);
        // Result : {Mike=HELLO MIKE, Stacey=HELLO STACEY, John=HELLO JOHN}
    }

}
```